# Rock identification ? What kind of it is?

Tags: rocks

My co-worker had this rock and told me found just behind the store, Big R, and put on the table in the office.

Location is Trindad, Colorado.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there anything more you can add after reading [this guide](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like slate to me. 
[The geological map of Trinidad suggests that the local rocks are shale, which is similar to slate but less compact.](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/Prodesc/proddesc_9346.htm)